# Подключение TabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragmenttabhost

Есть Viewpager с 3 страницами, пытаюсь поместить на первую вкладки.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grib"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Le Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTab1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Large Tt"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTab2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="La"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTab3" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment

```
public class Fragment  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

int pageNumber;

static Fragment newInstance(int page) {
    Fragment pageFragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;

    switch (pageNumber) {
        case 0:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actions_layout, null);

            break;
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
            break;

        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_layout, null);
            break;

    }
    return view;
}
```

Activity

```
public class GameMain_Activity extends FragmentActivity {

static final String TAG = "myLogs";
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(1);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

}

private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Fragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

Для создания вкладок есть код который надо вставить в активити в метод OnCreate, после чего выдаёт ошибку. Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException
Я понимаю, что пытаюсь обратиться к компоненту которого как бы не существует. Не понимаю как исправить

```
         TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    // инициализация
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

    // создаем вкладку и указываем тег
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    // название вкладки
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 1");
    // указываем id компонента из FrameLayout, он и станет содержимым
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tvTab1);
    // добавляем в корневой элемент
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    // указываем название и картинку
    // в нашем случае вместо картинки идет xml-файл, 
    // который определяет картинку по состоянию вкладки
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_selector));
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tvTab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
    // создаем View из layout-файла
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_header, null);
    // и устанавливаем его, как заголовок
    tabSpec.setIndicator(v);
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tvTab3);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    // вторая вкладка будет выбрана по умолчанию
    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("tag2");

    // обработчик переключения вкладок
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "tabId = " + tabId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы сказали, в какой именно строчке-то ошибка появляется. И, кстати, вы используете очень устаревший способ создания табов. Сейчас их надо через `TabLayout` делать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ошибка в логе

Comment: Думаю, вы не правы и ошибка таки в коде. А в логи выводится лишь информация о ней.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну ошибка появляется после добавления, последнего блока кода, в метод oncreate, в активити. Ну и я думаю ошибка в самой первой строчке
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

Comment: Вот надо было сразу сказать, что на сей строке ошибка. В таком большом объёме кода её с ходу вычислить сложно. См. ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = null;

switch (pageNumber) {
    case 0:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actions_layout, null);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

            tabHost.setup();
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
            tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
...
```

Comment: Т.е. вы таки искали TabHost в разметке его не имевшей.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб верно, ну и Id не совпадали

Answer (score 0):

Вы ищете ваш `TabHost` по неправильному `ID`. В разметке у вас

> android:id="@+id/tabHost"

а в коде:

> findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

т.е. некий системный `ID` вместо вашего. Замените на

```
findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
```

Comment: при изменении на tabHost он выделяет красным, а при изменении в xml на tabhost всё работает так же, точнее не работает так же

Comment: аа, не заметил вы удалили android, заменил, но ошибка осталась

Comment: Ошибка всё там же и всё та же? Имею в виду сообщение в логах. Там указан тип ошибки и строка её возникновения.

Comment: да 
02-29 09:35:34.406 10799-10799/com.mgomd.sim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 09:35:34.406 10799-10799/com.mgomd.sim E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mgomd.sim/com.mgomd.sim.GameMain_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 09:35:34.406 10799-10799/com.mgomd.sim E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

Comment: @Andrey, И на какой это строке?..

Comment: не показывает строку

Comment: @Andrey, быть такого не может. Поищите повнимательнее. А тип ошибки указывает, что вы где-то пытаетесь что-то сделать с переменной, коя равна `null`

Comment: Ну если не ошибаюсь это строка 64 - tabHost.setup();

Comment: Ну, значит у вас tabHost null. Значит вы таки, видимо, или не ту разметку загружаете или всё же неверный `ID` таки указали в findViewById

Comment: ну у меня  есть 4 разметки на одной сам viewpager и метод oncreate подключает её, а между остальными идёт слайдирование

Comment: @Andrey, я запутался. Где у вас ViewPager и где TabHost? В приведённой вами разметке я ViewPager вообще не вижу. И непонятно где вы написали код с TabHost